# Как проверить существует ли таблица в БД?

Tags: mysql

Как проверить существует ли таблица в БД?

SELECT * FROM `Tab` LIMIT 1

Слишком косвенно, к тому же такой запрос сначала выьерет все записи из таблицы, потом порежет до 1. Есть что-нибудь более изящьное?

Comment: есть одна бородатая шутка на эту тему...=)

Comment: Да видел я уже шутку эту ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'databasename'
AND table_name = 'tablename';
```

2.

```
show tables like 'tablename';
```